# Inner product for elements of Fourier basis

Tags: real-analysis, integration, fourier-transform, dirac-delta, quantum-mechanics

Assuming I have a infinite dimensional continuous Hilbert $\mathcal{H}$ space and an orthonormal basis $\{|\,x\,\rangle\}_{\mathbb{R}}$, I want to transform this basis with the Fourier transform to get the new basis $\{|\,p\,\rangle\}_{\mathbb{R}}$. So $$|\,p\,\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-ipx} |\,x\,\rangle\, dx$$Now I want to compute the inner product of two elements in this basis, which according to my material is orthonormal so $\langle\, p\, |\, q\,\rangle = \delta(p - q)$ should hold. But I can't quite follow the calculations. In particular I don't get the following step in the derivation: $$\langle\, p \,| \,q\, \rangle = \dots = \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-ix(q - p)} dx = \delta(q - p)$$

Comment: That is indeed a suspicious calculation, especially for the case of $p=q$. Does your material clarify what exactly they mean by an "integral" in this context? Are you sure that this is meant to be about the Fourier transform as opposed to Fourier series?

Comment: This is from a physics course so the things are not defined that strictly I guess. But yeah it is about the Fourier transform and not Fourier series.

Comment: $<x\mid x’> = \delta\left(x - x’\right)$

Comment: Note that in the solution given by md2perpe below that the physical interpretation of the distributional solution is that a "DC" signal that is only has an infinitely long period contribution should have all of it's power at zero frequency: $\delta(\xi)$

Answer (score 1):

This is a result from Fourier analysis of distributions.

The Fourier transform of $\delta(x)$ is
$$
\mathcal{F}\{\delta(x)\} = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \delta(x) \, e^{-ix\xi} \, dx = 1.
$$

By the Fourier inversion theorem, if $\mathcal{F}\{f(x)\} = g(\xi)$ then $\mathcal{F}\{g(x)\} = 2\pi \, f(-\xi)$. This is valid also for distributions, so applying it on the former result, we get
$$
\mathcal{F}\{1\} = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} 1 \, e^{-ix\xi} \, dx = 2\pi\,\delta(-\xi)
= 2\pi\,\delta(\xi)
.
$$

NB. Writing these Fourier transforms of distributions as integrals is actually abuse of notation. But it's an abuse that is common in physics.